# SQL Server 2008 R2 Query Designer: How to get a "picture" from a SQL statement?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using the SQL Server 2008 R2 "Query Designer" to design my SQL statements.
np at all.

But can this also made backwards?

Means how to get a "picture" like the Designer does from a SQL statement?

Comment: No clue what you want to hear..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you wish to see the Sql Statement in the Query Designer.

You can either paste the query in a new query window, highlight it and then select Query->Design Query in Editor,

Or you can just past the query into the Editor Sql Section (Box at the bottom of the Sql Design editor.

Comment: YES! That is what I am looking for! Thank you very much! Additional Question: Can "the picture" somehow be stored? Means I move and arrange the tables to get a really clear "picture" how everything is related - and I just want to save this nicely arranged view/picture. But how? Any good (3rd party) tools 4 that?